# Replay Kit iOS not working properly?

Tags: ios, ios11

In ios 11 beta, we have an option for screen recording in the control panel.  While selecting it, it should show the app lists which has enabled with Broadcast extensions(Replay kit).

But, in ios11 beta, it does not show any apps.

I have already installed the "MobCrush" app in my device.  In wwdc 2017, apple showed the ReplayKit demo with this app only.

I don't know if any fix in the next version updates.  Please share anything you know guys.

Comment: How can anyone possibly find a solution for this? We have zero information.

Comment: Its working. Thanks.

Comment: @Fogmeister Could you help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541509/replay-kit-not-working-ios11-bug?noredirect=1#comment80037808_46541509 ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how Tamil solved the issue, but in my case by restarting the device it started showing my own Broadcast Extension in Screen Recording setup.  But still no luck for MobCrush.  Maybe it should be built with new XCode?

Comment: MobCrush app may wait for iOS11 release.  I checked with my own broadcast extension. Its working.  Check with recent iOS beta 4 for restarting device issue. Thanks.