# ReplayKit saving video fails first try with mic

Tags: ios, iphone, avassetwriter, replaykit, rpscreenrecorder

Scenario 1:

1. Fire up AVAssetWriter with Audio / Video writer input.
2. Use RPScreenRecorder to start recording with no microphone and process the sample buffers.
3. File writes out fine to Photos on first try.

Scenario 2:

1. Fire up AVAssetWriter with Audio / Video writer input.
2. Use RPScreenRecorder to start recording with **microphone** enabled and process the sample buffers.
3. File writes fails to write out on the first try.

   UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try saving again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Save, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c464f3c0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12412 "(null)"}}
   2017-10-26 23:25:16.896673-0400 [2135:771655] Status FAILS!: 3 Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11823 "Cannot Save"

2nd try works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. did you find any solution?

Comment: @stanley nope. I think the AssetWriter is being started pre emptively but I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Are you using ios 11  see i have also added question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541509/replay-kit-not-working-ipad-ios11-bug

Comment: @JonSnow I am using 11.2. The issue is not related to that question. The issue pertains to an AssetWriter and the Microphone. That question has neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added retry logic to circumvent the issue. Not the greatest solution but it works.

```
[self.screenRecorder startCaptureWithHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef  _Nonnull sampleBuffer, RPSampleBufferType bufferType, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) == false || self.assetWriter == nil)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVWriter Failed!");
            return;
        }

        if (CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer)) {
            if(self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusWriting) {
                if (bufferType == RPSampleBufferTypeVideo) {
                    if (!self.startedSession) {

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            _startDate = [NSDate date];
                            _recordingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateRecordingTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

                            // Disable the idle timer while recording
                            [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
                        });

                        CMTime pts = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
                        [self.assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:pts];
                        self.startedSession = YES;
                        NSLog(@"MP4Writer: started session in appendVideoSample");
                    }

                    if (CMTimeCompare(kCMTimeInvalid, self.firstVideoFrameTime) == 0) {
                        self.firstVideoFrameTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
                    }

                    if (self.assetWriterVideoInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
                        @try {
                            [self.assetWriterVideoInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                        }
                        @catch(NSException *expection) {
                            NSLog(@"Missed Video Buffer: %@", self.assetWriter.error);
                        }
                    }
                }                

                if (bufferType == RPSampleBufferTypeAudioMic) {
                    if (CMTimeCompare(kCMTimeInvalid, self.firstVideoFrameTime) == 0 ||
                        CMTimeCompare(self.firstVideoFrameTime, CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)) == 1) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (!self.startedSession) {
                        CMTime pts = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
                        [self.assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:pts];
                        self.startedSession = YES;
                        NSLog(@"MP4Writer: started session in appendAudioSample");
                    }

                    if (self.assetWriterAudioInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {
                        @try {
                            [self.assetWriterAudioInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                        }
                        @catch(NSException *expection) {
                            NSLog(@"Missed Audio Buffer: %@", self.assetWriter.error);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    } completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Recording started successfully.");
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Turns out the real issue here was with how I was setting up my AssetWriter. I was doing something before it was ready.

Answer (score 2):

```
import Foundation
import ReplayKit
import AVKit
import Photos

class ScreenRecorder
{
    var assetWriter:AVAssetWriter!
    var videoInput:AVAssetWriterInput!
    var audioInput:AVAssetWriterInput!

    var startSesstion = false

  //  let viewOverlay = WindowUtil()

    //MARK: Screen Recording
    func startRecording(withFileName fileName: String, recordingHandler:@escaping (Error?)-> Void)
    {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
        {
            let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: ReplayFileUtil.filePath(fileName))
            assetWriter = try! AVAssetWriter(outputURL: fileURL, fileType:
                AVFileType.mp4)
            let videoOutputSettings: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.h264,
                AVVideoWidthKey : UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
                AVVideoHeightKey : UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height,
//                AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey : [
//                    AVVideoAverageBitRateKey :425000, //96000
//                    AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey : 1
//                ]
            ];
            var channelLayout = AudioChannelLayout.init()
            channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_MPEG_5_1_D
            let audioOutputSettings: [String : Any] = [
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 6,
                AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_HE,
                AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                AVChannelLayoutKey: NSData(bytes: &channelLayout, length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: channelLayout)),
                ]


            videoInput  = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video,outputSettings: videoOutputSettings)
            audioInput  = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.audio,outputSettings: audioOutputSettings)

            videoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
            audioInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

            assetWriter.add(videoInput)
            assetWriter.add(audioInput)

            RPScreenRecorder.shared().startCapture(handler: { (sample, bufferType, error) in
                recordingHandler(error)

                if CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sample)
                {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                        if self?.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.unknown {
                            print("AVAssetWriterStatus.unknown")
                            if !(self?.assetWriter.startWriting())! {
                                return
                            }
                            self?.assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sample))
                            self?.startSesstion = true
                        }

//                    if self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.unknown
//                    {
//                        self.assetWriter.startWriting()
//                        self.assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sample))
//                        self?.startSesstion = true
                    }
                    if self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.failed {

                        print("Error occured, status = \(String(describing: self.assetWriter.status.rawValue)), \(String(describing: self.assetWriter.error!.localizedDescription)) \(String(describing: self.assetWriter.error))")
                         recordingHandler(self.assetWriter.error)
                        return
                    }
                    if (bufferType == .video)
                    {
                        if(self.videoInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) && self.startSesstion {
                            self.videoInput.append(sample)
                        }
                    }
                    if (bufferType == .audioApp)
                    {
                        if self.audioInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData
                        {
                            //print("Audio Buffer Came")
                            self.audioInput.append(sample)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }) { (error) in
                recordingHandler(error)
//                debugPrint(error)
            }
        } else
        {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
    func stopRecording(isBack: Bool, aPathName: String ,handler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
    {

        //var isSucessFullsave = false
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
        {
            self.startSesstion = false
            RPScreenRecorder.shared().stopCapture{ (error) in
                self.videoInput.markAsFinished()
                self.audioInput.markAsFinished()

                handler(error)
                if error == nil{
                    self.assetWriter.finishWriting{
                         self.startSesstion = false
                        print(ReplayFileUtil.fetchAllReplays())
                        if !isBack{
                            self.PhotosSaveWithAurtorise(aPathName: aPathName)
                        }else{
                            self.deleteDirectory()
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                     self.deleteDirectory()
                }
            }
        }else {
           // print("Fallback on earlier versions")
        }
    }
    func PhotosSaveWithAurtorise(aPathName: String)  {
        if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .authorized {
            self.SaveToCamera(aPathName: aPathName)
        } else {
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status) in
                if status == .authorized {
                    self.SaveToCamera(aPathName: aPathName)
                }
            })
        }
    }
    func SaveToCamera(aPathName: String){
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: (ReplayFileUtil.fetchAllReplays().last)!)
        }) { saved, error in
            if saved {
                 addScreenCaptureVideo(aPath: aPathName)
                print("Save")
            }else{
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "isScreenRecordFaildToSave"), object: nil)
                print("error to save - \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    func deleteDirectory()  {
        ReplayFileUtil.delete()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello @Mahesh, Above code is working perfectly if we comment AudioInput code but it is crashing when I run app in iOS 13.1.  I got *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriterInput initWithMediaType:outputSettings:sourceFormatHint:] 6 is not a valid channel count for Format ID 'aach'.  Use kAudioFormatProperty_AvailableEncodeNumberChannels (<AudioToolbox/AudioFormat.h>) to enumerate available channel counts for a given format.' crash

Comment: @DikenShah did you manage to solve this and how? having same issue here...